# Как запустить sublime в нескольких браузерах?

Tags: sublime-text

Здравствуйте. Установил Sublime Text 2. Прикрутил к нему SideBarEnhancements. Теперь могу запускать файл, но только в одном браузере. Как запустить файл в нескольких браузерах, например, в Firefox, Chrome и IE по очереди?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там еще есть опция Open with, и если выбрать Edit Applications, откроется вот такой файл (мне иногда бывает необходимо картинку в ФШ открыть)

```
[
{"id": "side-bar-files-open-with",
    "children":
    [

        //application 1
        {
            "caption": "Photoshop",
            "id": "side-bar-files-open-with-photoshop",

            "command": "side_bar_files_open_with",
            "args": {
                                "paths": [],
                                "application": "Adobe Photoshop CS5.app", // OSX
                                "extensions":"psd|png|jpg|jpeg"  //any file with these extensions
                            }
        },

        {"caption":"-"}
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: я так понимаю надо в массивчик children воткнуть объект еще одного приложения. М?

Comment: Да, просто добавить несколько children для каждого браузера.